# Open an one XML layout into another XML Layout when button is pressed

Tags: android, android-layout

Basically, i have two XML files

1. weeks.xml
2. weekone.xml

Code for weeks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
Begin Relative Layout
-->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:background="@drawable/appbackground">



    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/about_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:background="#00141c"
    android:fontFamily="Hobo Std"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/backarrow" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/week4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingTop="400dp"
        android:src="@drawable/weekfour" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/week3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/week4"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingTop="400dp"
        android:src="@drawable/weekthree" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/week2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/week3"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingTop="400dp"
        android:src="@drawable/weektwo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/week1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/week2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingTop="400dp"
        android:src="@drawable/weekone" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hinttext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/week1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/backarrow"
        android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Press week1 to start workout" />

 <!-- 
 End of Relative Layout
  -->


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Code for weekone.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

             <!-- Begin of Linear Layout -->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/screenbackground"
    android:paddingTop="70dp" >

    <!--     Line seperator     -->

    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="#00141c"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/week1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/week1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#00141c"/>


            <!-- Begin Scrollable Relative Layout -->

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true">     


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/treadmillimage"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/treadmill" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/durOnTreadmill"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

            <!--     Line seperator     -->

    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="#00141c"/>




            <!--    End Relative Layout   -->

    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/treadmilltext"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/treadmill"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

<!--        Begin Relative Layou        -->

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stepperimage"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/stepper" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/durOnStepper"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <!--     Line seperator     -->

    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="#00141c"/>


         <!--   End Relative Layout  -->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/steppertext"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/stepper"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

<!--    Begin Relative Layout    -->

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stationaryrowing"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/stationaryrowing" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/durOnStationaryRowing"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <!--     Line seperator     -->

    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="#00141c"/>


<!--
End Relative Layout
-->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stationaryrowingtext"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/stationaryrowing"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

     <!--   Begin Relative Layout   -->
     <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exercisebikeimage"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ellipticaltrainer"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/durOnexcerisebike"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <!--     Line seperator     -->

    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="#00141c"/>

    <!--    End Relative Layout  -->

    </RelativeLayout>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/excerisebiketext"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/exercisebike"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <!--    Begin Relative Layout   -->

       <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:scrollHorizontally="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ellipticaltrainerimage"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ellipticaltrainer"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/durOnellipticaltrainer"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <!--     Line seperator     -->

    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="#00141c"/>

    <!--        End Relative Layout      -->

</RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ellipticaltrainertext"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/ellipticaltrainer"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

  </ScrollView>
<!--
End Linear Layout
-->
</LinearLayout>
```

So, what I want to achieve is, when I press click-able ImageView Week 1, it hides the Textview "hintText" and executes weekone.xml on the same activity. I have had a look regarding FrameLayout, as this is used to bring the layout on top of each other and I want both the layouts to be seen so doesn't suit my needs. ViewFlipper is used to change layout when you press on the blank space, but I want it to change when I press the button "Week 1"

Please help, I have been trying to resolve this since 2 days but no joy :(. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `hintText` in a `FrameLayout`, then call

```
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_framelayout_id);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
fl.removeAllViews();
fl.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.weekone, null));
```

This removes `hintText` from the `FrameLayout`, then loads `weekone.xml` and places its contents into the `FrameLayout` where `hintText` was.

In fact, `setContentView()`, which you are using in `onCreate()`, internally calls something very similar to place your XML in the main application window.

In a not very complex layout, another way would be using a static layout inclusion (you'd find that in Eclipse graphic layout editor in Layouts, look for "Include Other Layout") and putting its visibility to `gone`. Then you could call

```
findViewById(R.id.hintText).setVisibility(View.GONE);
findViewById(R.id.included_layout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

if you want to save a few lines of code.

Yet another way is to go "modern" and use fragment inclusion ([guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)). It takes some time to master but is definitely worth it in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i am curoius where to insert the FrameLayout lines of code.. I inserted in OnClick method, the application crashed and in the onCreate() still crashed. Additionally, i tired the visibility code as well but its still crashed

Comment: It worked mate, cheers, it wasn't working due to I having more than one child in the scrollview of weekone.xml. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood what you are trying to do, you can try to create a third layout which contains the two you already have. when you press Week1 the OnClick() method change the layout from weeks.xml to third.xml.

you can also create only a layout which contains the weeks.xml one whit visible=true and the other layout with visible=false. Clicking on the imageviews will set the corresponding layout visible=true.